# Is it possible to make an API call to initialize a Global Store in a React application?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, store

I am trying to make an API call to initialize the store provider in my React application, but I am having some kind of issue as I keep getting a promise instead of the result, even using async/await.

The initial store is set to:

```
const initialStore = {
    postData: {
        id: null,
        isLoading: true
    },
    breadcrumbs: {},
    user: getUserSesion()
}
```

Where `getUserSesion()` function:

```
export const getUserSesion = async () => {
    const userToken = localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN);

    if (!userToken) {
        return null
    }    

    const userSesionToken = jwt.decode(userToken, SECRET_KEY, true); 
    const userApiData = await getUser(userSesionToken.username); //gets user data

    return userApiData;
}
```

This is the error I get:

[image]

Comment: Your code doesn't show where you're calling `console.log`

Comment: `getUserSesion` itself becomes a promise since you're using `async` so it's behaving accordingly

Comment: @JuanMendes console.log is called inside the header component of my application, after global store initialization

Comment: @BrunoNoriller `userApiData` gets the correct data, but for some reason the data is not saved to global store.

Comment: As @brunonriller mentioned, For `const getValue = async () => 1`, `getValue()` returns a promise

Comment: Your const variable won't re-render. You should use a useState with initalState as initialStore and update it with useEffect. :)

Comment: Your initial store probably needs to await the result of `getUserSession()` `const initialStore = {postData: {id: null, isLoading: true}, breadcrumbs: {},  user: await getUserSesion()}`

Comment: It seems you are approaching the problem incorrectly. You should not make initializing the store wait, but instead you can separately dispatch an action ***to the store*** to populate the `user` state when the app starts.

Answer (score 0):

This has been already mentioned in comments but I want to transform it into an answer.

1. Your `getUserSesion` function becomes a promise as you are using the async keyword on the function, accordingly the function itself returns a type of promise,therefor you will have to await it when you call it.

```js
    const user = await getUserSesion();
```

```js
    getUserSesion().then((user) => /** do something */);
```

2. Your approach in initializing the data is wrong, instead of making the initial store state wait for your api call, you should initialize it as `null` and call your API when your app starts, readux has good resources on how you can accomplish this on their website:

   [Thunks with redux-toolkit](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux#writing-thunks)

   [Thunks with normal redux](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic#using-the-redux-thunk-middleware)

*EDIT* As pointed out in the comments I missed the fact that it was using redux so I updated the post to contain 2 links to redux docs that show how to handle async logic

Comment: OP is using Redux, not local component state.